# How to get dynamic variable's value inside a HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm currently using AngularJS, this is my HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr dir-paginate="tdata in tableData | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:searchFilter | itemsPerPage:10 track by $index ">
        <td class="table-data-edit-all">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tdata.selectedCell">
        </td>
        <td class="align-left">
            {{ tdata.companyName }}
        </td>
        <td class="align-left">
            {{ tdata.department }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a ng-click="editCompany({{ tdata.id }})"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a ng-click="removeCompany({{ tdata.id }})"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and here is Angular:

```
$scope.editCompany = function(index) {
    console.log(index);
    // my stuffs
}
```

When the page is loaded:

- first time, `tdata.id` show the number id `1` in HTML view and
  `editCompany(index)` also print out to the console number `1`.
- second time, after I did a `sort` using [Angular orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy),
  `tdata.id` show the number id `10` corresponding with
  `tdata.companyName`. However, at this time, `editCompany(index)` still
  print out to the console number `1`, not `10`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-click="editCompany(tdata.id)` instead of `ng-click="editCompany({{tdata.id}})`

```
<tbody>
    <tr dir-paginate="tdata in tableData | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:searchFilter | itemsPerPage:10 track by $index ">
        <td class="table-data-edit-all">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tdata.selectedCell">
        </td>
        <td class="align-left">
            {{ tdata.companyName }}
        </td>
        <td class="align-left">
            {{ tdata.department }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a ng-click="editCompany(tdata.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a ng-click="removeCompany(tdata.id)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thank you, it works like a charm. This stupid mistake took me 2 hours to find how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `{{ }}` from your code

**IN HTML**

```html
<tbody>
    <tr dir-paginate="tdata in tableData | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:searchFilter | itemsPerPage:10 track by $index ">
        <td class="table-data-edit-all">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tdata.selectedCell">
        </td>
        <td class="align-left">
            {{ tdata.companyName }}
        </td>
        <td class="align-left">
            {{ tdata.department }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <a ng-click="editCompany(tdata.id)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
            <a ng-click="removeCompany(tdata.id)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```